# Spark streaming reliable receiver and BlockGenerator?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, receiver

As I understand, when implementing a reliable receiver for spark streaming, the block generation needs to be taken care of in the custom receiver. Is this as easy as collecting some events to some kind of queue and then storing the iterator? Or should I use sparks BlockGenerator?

Are there any simple examples for initializing and using BlockGenerator in Java?